# "Because" in Japanese!

Tags: grammar

There are many many controversial topics in Japanese linguistics. And I believe that the "Because" is also one of them. Recently, I've been struggling between *から* and *ので* so hard...But I think I've got them a little bit from the former topics. And *boom*, today at class, my teacher gave me another not-really-new "Because"- ***理由のて型*** - ***"Because" of te-form.***

Can anyone give me some ideas how can I use it when we've got a lot of troubles with *から* and *ので*? And I've also heard that *ために* also has the meaning of "Because" too... But I haven't learnt *ために* yet...So please, just focus on the ***"Because" of te-form.*** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you separate a sentence in two (S1 and S2), you can use the te-form of the verbs to express reason or cause, where S1 is the reason or cause for S2, two events that occur sequentially, by consequence.

Examples of *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* book:

1.　ワインを飲みすぎて頭が痛い。= I've drunk too much wine and have a headache.

2.　このスープは辛くて飲めない。= This soup is salty (or (spicy) hot) and I can't drink/eat it.

3.　私はテニスが大好きでよく友達とする。= I love tennis and often play with my friends.

As you can note, te-form don't have exactly the same meaning as から and ので, that are usually used to explain a reason for something, I think is more about a way to show a consequence of a action or state.

Both forms has a lot of different meanings and usages, you will get used with them with time and continuous study. I'm trying as well xD